# boto3 update_security_group_rule_descriptions_ingress error

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto, boto3

I get error using boto3 to update security group ingress IP:

> botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidPermission.NotFound) when calling the UpdateSecurityGroupRuleDescriptionsIngress operation: The specified rule does not exist in this security group.

My code look like:

```
def get_security_group_detail(name, client=None):
    if not client:
        client = boto3.client = boto3.client(
            'ec2',
            region_name=config.aws_region,
            aws_secret_access_key=config.aws_secret_access_key,
            aws_access_key_id=config.aws_access_key_id
        )
    response = client.describe_security_groups(
        Filters=[
            {'Name': 'group-name', 'Values': [name]}
        ])
    return response['SecurityGroups'][0]

def update_security_group_ingress_ip(name, ip_list, client=None):
    if not client:
        client = boto3.client = boto3.client(
            'ec2',
            region_name=config.aws_region,
            aws_secret_access_key=config.aws_secret_access_key,
            aws_access_key_id=config.aws_access_key_id
        )
    new_ip_list = []
    for ip in ip_list:
        new_ip_list.append({'CidrIp': ip})

    sg = get_security_group_detail(name, client)
    group_id = sg['GroupId']
    ip_permission = sg['IpPermissions']

    for rule in ip_permission:
        rule['IpRanges'] += new_ip_list
        if len(rule['UserIdGroupPairs']) == 0:
            rule['UserIdGroupPairs'] = [{
                'GroupId': group_id,
                'GroupName': sg['GroupName'],
                'VpcId': sg['VpcId']
            }]

    response = client.update_security_group_rule_descriptions_ingress(
        DryRun=False,
        GroupId=group_id,
        IpPermissions=ip_permission
    )
    return response
```

As the [documentation](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.update_security_group_rule_descriptions_ingress) mentioned. I already provide `GroupId` because the Security Group I need to update not always in default VPC but I still get error.

I tried to add `VpcId` in `UserIdGroupPairs` inside each `IpPermissions` but didn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given I understand the intent of your code correctly, it seems to me you are using the wrong method:
`update_security_group_rule_descriptions_ingress()` is used to update the **Description** of an **existing** ingress rule.
If your goal is to add an ingress rule to a group, look at `authorize_security_group_ingress()` instead.